# Error: "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm making a To-Do list and I got this error *"Type '{ id: number; text: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': item, handleDelete"*. I don't know how to fix this any more. Thanks

from App.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import TodoComponent from './TodoComponent'

interface Todo {
    id: number
    text: string
}

function App() {
    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState<string>('')
    const [todoArray, setTodoArray] = useState<Array<Todo>>([{ id: 0, text: '' }])
    const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(1)

    const handleClick = () => {
        if (inputText !== '') setCount(count + 1)
        setTodoArray([...todoArray, { id: count, text: inputText }])
        setInputText('')
    }

    const handleDelete = (id: number) => {
        console.log('click', id)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={inputText} onChange={e => setInputText(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>

            {todoArray.map(item => {
                return <TodoComponent {...item} {...handleDelete}/>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

from TodoComponent.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
    item: {id: number, text: string}
    handleDelete: (id: number) => void
}

function TodoComponent(todo: Props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {todo.item.text}
            {todo.item.text !== '' && <button onClick={() => todo.handleDelete(todo.item.id)}>x</button>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoComponent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the props this way:

```
{todoArray.map(item => {
            return <TodoComponent item={item} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
})}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks. I tried that before but I got some error so I found on stack that I should use this syntax: {...smth} and still got another error haha

Comment: No problem, when you pass the object using spread operator it extracts the properties (key, value) and passes to Props, so if the Props interface have the same properties as the passed object, then it will work fine.